# Execute PHP Session from within JS Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to set a PHP session without reloading the page when a user clicks a button. Ideally, the button click would immediately hide the div named download_div and would set the session "close_download" to true.

I understand that JS is user-side and that PHP is server-side, but I'm wondering if there is a way to blend the two worlds. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closeDownload()
{
$('.download_div').hide()
}

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['close_download'] = "true";
?>

</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="close_download.php" data-role="button" onClick="closeDownload()">Close</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use Ajax call to use SESSION

Comment: ever heard about ajax?

Comment: AJAX AJAX AJAX is your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['close_download'] = "true";
?>
```

`download.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closeDownload()
{
   $('.download_div').hide()
   $.get("session.php")   
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="close_download.php" data-role="button" onClick="closeDownload()">Close</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ajax, read the documents on jquery ajax calls, is the fastest way.

basically you have to have another php file that has this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['close_download'] = "true";
```

Then in your html/js you do something like $.get('newfile.php');

You can't put php in your javascript, but using ajax you can 'blend' them as u said

Answer (score 1):

The way to blend the two worlds is - [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: "session.php",
  data: {'name': 'test_session', 'value': 'foobar'}
}).done(function() {
     $('#notification').html('Done!');
});
```

session.php-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
?>
```